# C++: is `X&& goo();` a function declaration or a variable definition?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm reading [this tutorial](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html). I found the following code snippet.

```cpp
X&& goo(); // (1)
X x = goo(); // (2)
```

I think `X` is a class name, but I don't understand what `X&& goo();` does. I suppose there are two possibilities:

1. It declares a function `goo` which returns a rvalue reference to X.
2. It declares a variable `goo` and calls the default constructor (without arguments) of X.

But if 1 is true then since there is no function body how can it be called? And if 2 is true then what does line (2) do?

I tried to search for this syntax but wasn't able to figure out the correct keywords. Can anyone give a hint? Thanks!

Comment: All the *compiler* need to know to be able to call a function is to know that the function exists *somewhere*. It's then the *linker* which checks that the functions actually exists (are defined).

Comment: And yes, `X&& goo();` is a function declaration. It declares a function named `goo` which takes no arguments and an rvalue reference to an `X` object.

Comment: It seems like it's a bit early for you to worry about rvalue references. Start with the basics in a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thomas Becker is a good C++ writer.  He writes about specific aspects of C++, especially back when those were novel introductions to the language.  What you are reading is am explanatory article to those novel aspects, not a tutorial to C++.  I recommend you consider learning C++ from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116) rather than narrowly focused article exploring a novel feature somewhat in isolation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and book recommendations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is `X&& goo();` a function declaration or a variable definition?

It is not a variable definition. If `X` is a type name, then it is a function declaration. If `X` is a variable and `goo` is callable, then it is an expression statement.

> But if 1 is true then since there is no function body how can it be called?

It can be called using the function call expression: `goo()`.

The definition of the function contains the body. If the function is odr-used (calling the function is an example of odr-use), then the function must be defined somewhere else. If it isn't defined anywhere, then the program is ill-formed (with no diagnostic required).